# Are there any special steps when installing drywall over vapour barrier?

Tags: drywall, vapor-barrier

I have a simple (I think) question about installing drywall overtop vapour barrier.

Obviously the drywall screw will puncture the vapour barrier.  What is typically done to prevent that puncture from rendering the vapour barrier useless?

I'm sure there must be a way, I just can't figure the right Google keywords to use to find the answer.

**Edit:** I ended using acoustic sealant along the stud where the screw goes in.  It's viscous but tacky, so it can create a bit of an additional seal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, nothing is done. That puncture should be at a tight connection of drywall to stud, where airflow is impeded by the pressure of the screw holding the drywall and vapor barrier to the stud.

The vapor barrier isn't an impermeable seal, it just dramatically reduces movement of air and vapor between interior space and exterior walls.