Avoid perforating damp screen
I am insulating an exterior wall from the inside with mineral wool, metal studs, and plaster boards. I understand that I should attach a damp screen in between the insulating layer and the plaster boards. However, it seems to me that I would have to perforate the damp screen with the screws used to attach the plaster board. Am I not understanding something?

Do you mean a vapor barrier?  Typically, a few holes in a vapor barrier aren't a problem, unless you have significant air flow through the barrier.

yes indeed... so i can just screw through it?

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15329/are-there-any-special-steps-when-installing-drywall-over-vapour-barrier
